# why our C++ class is forced abstract?

Tags: c#, .net, class, c++-cli, abstract-class

Why when we inherit an abstract C# class defined in a .dll, our C++-CLI class is forced abstract?
is there any way to make it not abstract our c++-CLI class?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but you have to implement all the methods declared but not implemented in the abstract base class, otherwise naturally your class is considered abstract as well.

Comment: Correct, but your terminology is slightly off: you must non-purely implement all the pure methods in the base.  It is possible to implement a pure method; this is most commonly seen with implementations of pure dtors.

Answer (score 2):

If your class declares any methods that are "pure virtual" (i.e., with "= 0"), or inherits any pure virtual methods without overriding them, your class will be abstract.

Answer (score 2):

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void fun() = 0; //"pure" virtual function
    virtual void gun() = 0; //"pure" virtual function

    virtual void sun() //virtual function - "not pure"
    {
      /***** implementation code *****/
    }
};
```

Here `A` is an abstract class, since it has two pure virtual functions.

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void fun() 
    {
       /******* implementation code ********/
    }
};
```

**Question:** What is `B`? Is it non-abstract? After all, it has defined/implemented one *pure* virtual function called `fun()`?

**Answer :** No. `B` too is an abstract class, because it didn't define/implement `gun()` which too is *pure* virtual function in the base class `A`. Defining just one *pure* virtual function called `fun()` doesn't make it non-abstract. It has to define ALL **pure** virtual functions. ALL means ALL, as many as there are **pure** virtual functions.

So two important notes here : **1) pure virtual functions, 2) define all of them.** Only then a class can become concrete/non-abstract!